# Getting "duplicate symbol _main" while embedding unity in existing swift project

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I am trying to embed a unity project into an existing swift project.
I am getting the following error:

> duplicate symbol _main in:
>       /Users/vikasroy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CaptainCreek-fohhjxvaawusmeeuopzkmqmiplys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CaptainCreek.build/Debug-iphoneos/CaptainCreek.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.o
>       /Users/vikasroy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CaptainCreek-fohhjxvaawusmeeuopzkmqmiplys/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CaptainCreek.build/Debug-iphoneos/CaptainCreek.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any idea what the problem can be?

When I delete the `@UIApplicationMain` annotation from the **AppDelegate** file, it works but then Unity Player opens directly at the launch.

My App has got a different main screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unity generated code contains another main method in the file main.mm. This method must be renamed to resolve the error. 
Although you will need the code from the generated main to initialise the Unity Player.

Furthermore you need more steps to succeed in embedding the unity project:
- You will need to link all the required libraries and
- Save an instance of the UnityAppController in your AppDelegate and make it accessible via the UnityAppController.h

There is a project on GitHub where all those modifications are automated: https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity

Comment: I am able to get the successful build after renaming main.mm. But my app is now opening with unity as default. I have a different home screen. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you add the `@UIApplicationMain` to your AppDelegate? Then it should start with your ViewController. For an example how to start the UnityPlayer from within your AppDelegate check the swift-unity project:  https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity

Comment: Yes, I have added @UIApplicationMain to AppDelegate. When I launch the app, I can see my custom home screen for a moment then the unity player appears on the top of it.

Comment: You wrote that you renamed the file `main.mm`, but the method should be renamed.  If that does not help it is difficult to analyse without seeing some code.

Comment: Can this be some issue with Unity 2019?

Comment: Possible, as i never tried to embed a Unity 2019 project, what does make you think it does, did it work in 2018?
But i don't think the way of initialising the Unity Player would have changed dramatically since Unity 2018.
  
To further track the problem down, you could try to add some logging in your Classes and the Unity-Classes or better use breakpoints to get the callstack.